# How do I create a specific date in HSQLDB?

Tags: java, spring, hsqldb

I need to create a HIGH date in HSQLDB and the solution is eluding me.  I need something like

```
Date(9999-12-31 0:0:0)
```

but I cannot find a function or whatever to do it.  I am loding the date via Spring on startup and i need something like:

```
insert intoMOD (
  ITM_INST_ELECTR_MOD_STRT_TS,
  ITM_INST_ID,
  ELECTR_MOD_ID,
  ITM_INST_ELECTR_MOD_END_TS
) VALUES (
  CURRENT_DATE,
  0,
  0,
  Date(9999-12-31 0:0:0)
)
```

What is the way to create a specific data using SQL in Hypersonic?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Given the [user guide](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/sqlgeneral-chapt.html#sgc_datetime_types), I'd expect the following to work:

```
DATE '9999-12-31'
```

or, if you need more than day precision:

```
TIMESTAMP '9999-12-31 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Thanks.  I couldn't find it.  My google fu failed me.  I can't believe there are no parenthesis around the date...

Answer (score 5):

I was struggling with this problem and I think that I can contribute to help some other people.

Here is the insert that you need to put on your script while loading hsqldb:

```
insert intoMOD (
  ITM_INST_ELECTR_MOD_STRT_TS,
  ITM_INST_ID,
  ELECTR_MOD_ID,
  ITM_INST_ELECTR_MOD_END_TS
) VALUES (
  CURRENT_DATE,
  0,
  0,
  '9999-12-31'
)
```

HSQLDB converts the string automatically.

I tested with latest version (2.3.3).

Comment: Nice addition.  Thanks!